# Regex java from javascript

Tags: java, javascript, regex

Hello I have this regex in Javascript :

```
var urlregex = new RegExp("((www.)(([a-zA-Z0-9-]){2,}\.){1,4}([a-zA-Z]){2,6}(\/([a-zA-Z-_\/\.0-9#:?=&;,]*)?)?)");
```

And when I try to put it on a Java String I have this error :

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are  \b  \t  \n  \f  \r  \"  \'  \\ )   CreateActivity.java /SupLink/src/com/supinfo/suplink/activities line 43 Java Problem
```

So I just want to know what I have to change to render it in Java in order to do this(this function runs fine) :

```
private boolean IsMatch(String s, String pattern) 
    {
        try {
            Pattern patt = Pattern.compile(pattern);
            Matcher matcher = patt.matcher(s);
            return matcher.matches();
        } catch (PatternSyntaxException e){
            return false;
        }
}
```

**EDIT :**

Thank you for your help, now I have this :

```
private String regex = "((www.)(([a-zA-Z0-9-]){2,}\\.){1,4}([a-zA-Z]){2,6}(\\/([a-zA-Z-_\\/\\.0-9#:?=&;,]*)?)?)";
```

But I don't match what I really want (regex are horrible ^^), I would like to match thes types of urls :

- www.something.com
- something.com
- something.com/anotherthing/anything

Can you help me again ?

really thanks

Comment: There are lots of characters you need to escape with a backslash in Java. You also need to use two backslashes in Java regexes: one to escape the characater in the regex, another to escape the backslash in the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently your regex require `www` at start. If you want to make it optional add `?` after `(www.)`. Also you probably want to escape `.` after `www` part. Your regex should probably look like.

```
"((www\\.)?(([a-zA-Z0-9-]){2,}\\.){1,4}([a-zA-Z]){2,6}(\\/([a-zA-Z-_\\/\\.0-9#:?=&;,]*)?)?)"
```

Answer (score 3):

When you create the Java string, you need to escape the backslashes a second time so that Java understands that they are literal backslashes. You can replace all existing backslashes with `\\`. You also need to escape any Java characters that normally need to be escaped.

Comment: [java.util.regex.Pattern.quote()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote(java.lang.String)) may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You should scape \

something like this

```
"((www.)(([a-zA-Z0-9-]){2,}\\.){1,4}([a-zA-Z]){2,6}(\\/([a-zA-Z-_\\/\\.0-9#:?=&;,]*)?)?)"
```